# How can I do 'from foo import bar as b' with imp in Python2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

I need to import a module without knowing it's location in advance; The user will specify the location as an argument to my script.

I know I can use `imp` for imports, like

```
import imp
foo = imp.load_source('foo', '/path/to/foo.py')
```

which is functionally equivalent to

```
import foo
```

if foo was found in PATH.

How can I construct something similar to

```
from foo import bar as b
```

?

Comment: `b = imp.load_source('foo', '/path/to/foo.py).bar`?

Comment: @Blckknght you should post it as an answer.

Comment: And no, it is not functionally equivalent to `import foo`. `load_source` unconditionally loads the module code and creates a module for it.

Answer (score 0):

As I commented, you can use normal attribute access to get the `bar` object from the module object returned from `imp.load_source`, even within the same expression:

```
b = imp.load_source('foo', '/path/to/foo.py').bar
```

This isn't quite the same as `from foo import bar as b`, since `load_source` always reads the source file and creates a new module object with new contents. An `import` statement will only load the module once, and use the cached version of it from `sys.modules` if you import it again.